# NGINX: Remove WordPress subdirectory from url

Tags: directory, nginx, mod-rewrite, composer

I have installed WordPress core in a subdirectory as I am using composer.

The root is `/www/example.com/` and WordPress is placed in `/www/example.com/wp/`

In the root is `index.php` and `wp-config.php`.

The home url is https://example.com and the site url is https://example.com/wp

The front end works fine but the admin url has always the WordPress folder in it. e.g. https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/

How can I remove the `wp` from https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/ from the URL?

Comment: You'll have to maintain a long list of internal URL rewrites to achieve that. However, my question is: what's wrong with accessing admin URL's using `https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/`?

Comment: The list should be able to be made smaller with regex. This is possible with apache. It is an aesthetics reason.